# cannot remove rewrite rule (selected) using php from .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

(solved) i trying to delete selected rewrite rule content/code from htaccess but its response coming coudnot find and unable to clear/delete any one know whats the problem? my permission is 644 for htaccess
**SOLUTION**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
    $delete_id = $_GET['delete_id'];

    // Get the page slug for the deleted page
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT page_slug FROM tbl_page WHERE page_id=?");
    $statement->execute([$delete_id]);
    $page_slug = $statement->fetchColumn();

    $htaccess_path = '../.htaccess';
$htaccess_content = file_get_contents($htaccess_path);

$rewrite_rule = "RewriteRule ^".$page_slug."/?$ page/".$page_slug." [NC,L]";
$pattern = "/".preg_quote($rewrite_rule, '/')."/";
$htaccess_content = preg_replace($pattern, '', $htaccess_content, 1, $count);

if ($count === 0) {
    $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Error: Could not find RewriteRule for ' . $page_slug . ' in .htaccess';
} else {
    // Rewrite rule removed successfully
    // Write the updated .htaccess content back to the file
    file_put_contents($htaccess_path, $htaccess_content);
    if ($htaccess_content === false) {
        $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Error deleting RewriteRule from .htaccess';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['success_message'] = 'RewriteRule deleted successfully.';
    }
}


    // Delete the page from the database
    $statement = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM tbl_page WHERE page_id = ?');
    $statement->execute([$delete_id]);

    header('Location: ' . BASE_URL_ADMIN . 'page');
    exit;
}
?>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
    $delete_id = $_GET['delete_id'];

    // Get the page slug for the deleted page
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT page_slug FROM tbl_page WHERE page_id=?");
    $statement->execute([$delete_id]);
    $page_slug = $statement->fetchColumn();

    // Remove the corresponding RewriteRule from the .htaccess file
    $htaccess_path = '../.htaccess';
    if (file_exists($htaccess_path) && is_writable($htaccess_path)) {
        $htaccess_content = file_get_contents($htaccess_path);
        $htaccess_content = preg_replace("/RewriteRule \^" . preg_quote($page_slug, '/') . "\/?$ page\/" . preg_quote($page_slug, '/') . " \[NC,L\]\n?/m", '', $htaccess_content, 1, $count);

        if ($count === 0) {
            echo 'Error: Could not find RewriteRule for ' . $page_slug . ' in .htaccess';
        } else {
            file_put_contents($htaccess_path, $htaccess_content);

            if ($htaccess_content === false) {
                echo 'Error deleting RewriteRule from .htaccess';
            } else {
                echo 'RewriteRule for ' . $page_slug . ' has been successfully removed from .htaccess';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error deleting RewriteRule from .htaccess';
    }
}
?>
```

this is my htaccess data

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the requested file or directory does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite the URL to append .php and try again
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# If the requested directory exists, add a trailing slash and try again
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ewewe/?$ page/ewewe [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ffffff/?$ page/ffffff [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^demo/?$ page/demo[NC,L]
```

i am expecting a solution which allow me to delete the selected htaccess content

Comment: ok, so show us a `.htaccess` file and show us an example of what is entered by the user or the page_slug .

Comment: done, am new here so i dont know whats the rule , sorry for my mistake

Comment: So now what will `$page_slug` be set to?

Comment: it set to slug of  page, and create a code to make rewrite rule like

Comment: RewriteRule ^demo/?$ page/demo[NC,L] like this

Comment: This is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). The web server process that runs this script should not have the ability to write to the files it serves, and _especially not_ to the files that configure it. This sort of dynamic rewrite service should be performed by a [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller).

Comment: but i run a code , which remove all .htaccess data

Comment: `" \[NC,L\]\n?/m"` - why is the expression you are creating containing a newline character? And you have a space before the `[NC,L]` part, which your actual line in the .htaccess does not.

Comment: And you want to match a literal `?` here, `demo/?`, so that question mark would also need to be escaped to not be taken as a quantifier.

Comment: can you give me the solution?

Comment: i means a code am little confused

Comment: $pattern = "/RewriteRule \^" . preg_quote($page_slug, '/') . "-?/?\$ page\/" . preg_quote($page_slug, '/') . " \[NC,L\]/m";
 do telling me like this?